How to pass a list of JSON as formdata to DRF
Consider this as my serializer:
class EmployeeDataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    firstname = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    lastname = serializers.CharField(required=True)


class OfficeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    employee_data = EmployeeDataSerializer(required=False, many=True, allow_null=True, allow_empty=True)
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = OfficeModel
        fields = (
            ...
            employee_data,
            ...
        )

I can pass and process the employee_data as a list of JSON when posting a JSON to this endpoint such as this:
{"employee_data": [{"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe"}, {"firstname": "Sarrah", "lastname": "Jackson"}]}

But I could not find a way to also be able to POST the data as formdata and have it as JSON in the serializer. Is that even possible?
